# Keep getting warning MSB3245 on dotnet build

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I keep getting this error when i try to use Azure Pipelines.

I am running this on the Hosted VS2017 pool.

Here is the pipeline i constructed:

[image: Overview Pipeline - dotnet restore]

[image: Overview Pipeline - dotnet build]

The error i keep getting is displayed in the following logs:

```
2019-04-30T12:13:03.1506572Z =============================================================================
2019-04-30T12:13:03.1506616Z Task         : .NET Core
2019-04-30T12:13:03.1506659Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2019-04-30T12:13:03.1506705Z Version      : 2.150.1
2019-04-30T12:13:03.1506734Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-04-30T12:13:03.1506782Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2019-04-30T12:13:03.1506811Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-30T12:13:03.7965121Z [command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2019-04-30T12:13:03.8059420Z Active code page: 65001
2019-04-30T12:13:03.8489997Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build D:\a\1\s\SLDatatHighway.Tests\SLDatatHighway.Tests.csproj
2019-04-30T12:13:04.1500736Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
2019-04-30T12:13:04.1501599Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2019-04-30T12:13:04.1501793Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:04.8585498Z   Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\SLDatatHighway.Tests\SLDatatHighway.Tests.csproj...
2019-04-30T12:13:05.0444966Z   Restore completed in 185.75 ms for D:\a\1\s\SLDatatHighway.Tests\SLDatatHighway.Tests.csproj.
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0489863Z   SLDatatHighway.Tests -> D:\a\1\s\SLDatatHighway.Tests\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SLDatatHighway.Tests.dll
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0572034Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0572433Z Build succeeded.
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0572907Z     0 Warning(s)
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0573263Z     0 Error(s)
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0573380Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0573422Z Time Elapsed 00:00:02.84
2019-04-30T12:13:07.0915364Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build D:\a\1\s\SL_DataHighway.Tests\SL_DataHighway.Tests.csproj
2019-04-30T12:13:07.3764095Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
2019-04-30T12:13:07.3807448Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2019-04-30T12:13:07.3807518Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:08.1015074Z   Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\SL_DataHighway.Tests\SL_DataHighway.Tests.csproj...
2019-04-30T12:13:08.7878736Z   Restore completed in 484.69 ms for D:\a\1\s\SL_DataHighway.Tests\SL_DataHighway.Tests.csproj.
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0395526Z   SL_DataHighway.Tests -> D:\a\1\s\SL_DataHighway.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\SL_DataHighway.Tests.dll
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0481411Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0482045Z Build succeeded.
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0483401Z     0 Warning(s)
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0483487Z     0 Error(s)
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0483908Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0484034Z Time Elapsed 00:00:06.60
2019-04-30T12:13:14.0864499Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj
2019-04-30T12:13:14.3705111Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
2019-04-30T12:13:14.3705588Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2019-04-30T12:13:14.3705720Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:14.8626284Z   Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
2019-04-30T12:13:15.3736897Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj]
2019-04-30T12:13:15.3779682Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj]
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4465770Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveComReference" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj]
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4550056Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4554234Z Build FAILED.
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4554556Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4574427Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj]
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4579425Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj]
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4580177Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveComReference" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj]
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4583312Z     2 Warning(s)
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4583865Z     1 Error(s)
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4585281Z 
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4585654Z Time Elapsed 00:00:01.01
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4950879Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4960391Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\SL_Data_Highway_App\SL_Data_Highway_App.csproj
2019-04-30T12:13:15.4994396Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet build
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5009622Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5109587Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5109634Z Task         : Get sources
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5109671Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5109870Z Version      : 1.0.0
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5109906Z Author       : Microsoft
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5109940Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2019-04-30T12:13:15.5109992Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-30T12:13:15.9176300Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: SL-DataHighway (Git)
2019-04-30T12:13:15.9266683Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout
2019-04-30T12:13:15.9371889Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2019-04-30T12:13:15.9414810Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2019-04-30T12:13:15.9425504Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
2019-04-30T12:13:15.9475730Z ##[section]Finishing: Job
```

Building via Visual Studio 2017 works fine. Problem is only when I try to build via an Azure Pipeline.

Is there something I am missing or did I import something wrong?
Here is an overview of the references in my project. As you can see the Outlook Interop is referenced fine as well as the Office reference.

[image: Overview references in project]

My packages.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" version="15.0.4797.1003" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Added pool, Added overview of packages.config

Comment: How were the references added?  Local machine/GAC or via nuget?

Comment: Only the Interop.Outlook is done with NuGet, the others are done by right-clicking References, Add Reference etc.

Comment: We have some custom libs for database connectivity that is not available in nuget or on azure devops build servers.  So we have a folder called _References_ in our project where we copy .dll files then reference them in the project that way.  When building the project in DevOps it uses those references.  Is that something you could try?